# Saving new entry with spring-data-jpa

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have a MySQL table with some default column values, and the RestController.
When i POST to /orders endpoint i send a JSON object and i get a response that contains the information i have sent + the auto-generated ID of the MySQL entry.

What can i do to make the request return the full entry that has been saved in the database including the default column values? I know, the ID that i get in the response, i can use it to make a GET request in order to retrieve all the data but i don't want to make a new request.

MySQL Orders table

```
  `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `delivery_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

OrdersModel

```
@Entity
@Table(name="orders")
@Getter @Setter @DynamicUpdate @DynamicInsert
public class OrderModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="order_date")
    Date orderDate;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="delivery_date")
    Date deliveryDate;
    
    protected OrderModel() {}
}
```

Spring RestController

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("orders")
public class OrdersController {
    private final OrdersRepository ordersRepo;
    
    @ResponseBody
    @PostMapping
    public OrderModel addOrder(@RequestBody OrderModel order) {
        return ordersRepo.saveAndFlush(order);
    }
}
```

POST request body:

```
 {}
```

POST response body:

```
{
    "id":40,
    "orderDate":null,
    "deliveryDate":null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use, only where you need it, the EntityManager's **refresh(Object entity)** method on the entity you want to save in the database and to get it back.

Another solution is to use the same **refresh(Object entity)** method in a **repository base class** to make it global and not change anything else as follows:

1. Create a new custom **repository base class** that overrides the **save** method. (include the refresh(Object entity))
2. Let spring-boot know you want it to use the custom repository base class you just made.

- Now when you call a repository's save() method it will use the one you created in the repository base class.

```
    public class CustomBaseRepository<T, ID> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> {
        private final EntityManager entityManager;
        private final JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation;

        CustomBaseRepository(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?>  entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
            super(entityInformation, entityManager);
            this.entityManager = entityManager;
            this.entityInformation = entityInformation;
        }

        @Transactional
        @Override
        public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
            if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
                entityManager.persist(entity);
                //the next line of code saves the entry in the database for real and updates the entity object with the new information
                entityManager.refresh(entity);
                return entity;
            } else {
                return entityManager.merge(entity);
            }       
        }
    }
```

```
        @SpringBootApplication
        @EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = CustomBaseRepository.class)
        public class Application {
        
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);     
            }
        }
```